# How to change the backgroungColor cell in tableView with timeInterval using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I'm trying to change the cell backgroungColor after 3.5 month. I have a textField where i put the date and after 3.5 month of that date I want to change the color of the cell in red.

I tried this where date1 is the date from textField and date2 is this from (isToday) where i have put 106 day = 3.5 month

```
 let isToday= Date.now.addingTimeInterval(106)

func isSameDay(date1: Date, date2: Date) -> Bool {
    let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    if diff.day == 0 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Inside **cellForRowAt** i have used like this

```
     var documentSendDate = "05.08.2022"// this is example to be more understandable

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: documentSendDate)

    if date != nil {
        let isDayToday = isSameDay(date1: date!, date2: isToday) // here I call the function above

        if isDayToday  == true {

            if customer.isToday == true {
                cell.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }
    }
```

But I have this checkBox and when I check it or uncheck it change the color of the random cells. **Can someone help me with this please?**
[image]

**Here is how i wanted to look.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`UITableView` is a recycle-list view, so it will reuse the cell UI instance to display data for the corresponding indexPath.

First, modify your code to add a new way of **dateFormatter** declaration.

```
// Use lazy var to reduce initialization cost
// Because initializing a new DateFormatter is not cheap, it can consume CPU time like initializing a new NumberFormatter
// lazy var will be only initialized once on the first call/use
lazy var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy"
}
```

It is a reusable UI, so UI won't hold the data or state. The `cellForRowAt` will be called multiple times when you scroll tableView or when tableView needs to re-layout,... to display the corresponding data-state for each indexPath.
That is why you must not initialize or do some big calculations/long waiting here. It will freeze/delay your UI (ref: DispatchQueue.main or MainQueue).

So inside your `cellForRowAt` function, you need to add logic for all cases if you use switch/if-else.

```
     var documentSendDate = "05.08.2022"// this is example to be more understandable

    // Here I combine all checks into one if-else
    // Order of check is left-to-right.
    // It is condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 (swift syntax)
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: documentSendDate),
        let isDayToday = isSameDay(date1: date!, date2: isToday),
        customer.isToday == true {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear // or your desired color
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me I spend 1 week finsind a good solution for this, Please can you help me with time interval where i can put the number of days when i want the cell to be red? Because this is not working  let isToday= Date.now.addingTimeInterval(106)

Comment: Glad to know that solves your problem!

Comment: let isToday= Date.now.addingTimeInterval(106)
This call just adds 106 seconds to your Date.now
It is just 1 min 46 seconds.
If you want to add 106 days, you can calculate 106 days in seconds and then add it to your Date.now. 1 day = 86400 seconds.

TimeInterval mostly refers to Second.

Comment: My first idea was exactly like your, but the way i solve it was by updating my func **isSameDay** to return an int with number of the day `(date1: documentSendDate, date2: date.now)`. Then inside **cellForRowAt** I check if isToday >= 106 i change the color of the cell. And as i made some test this work for me.